# Are these $\pi$ approximating algorithms known?

Tags: algorithms, approximation, pi

I was fiddling around with inscribed and circumscribed n-gons of a circle, and using a couple $\sin$ and $\tan$ formulas I came up with two algorithms that approximate $\pi$ pretty fast.

The first algorithm approximates $\pi$ from below:
$$
\begin{align}
&1. \text{ Let } p \leftarrow \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } n \leftarrow 4 \\
&2. \text{ Keep repeating: } p \leftarrow \frac{1-\sqrt{1-p}}{2} \text{ and } n \leftarrow 2n \\
&3. \ \pi \approx n\sqrt{p}
\end{align}
$$

The second algorithm approximates $\pi$ from above:
$$
\begin{align}
&1. \text{ Let } p \leftarrow 1 \text{ and } n \leftarrow 4 \\
&2. \text{ Keep repeating: } p \leftarrow \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+p^2}}{p} \text{ and } n \leftarrow 2n \\
&3. \ \pi \approx np
\end{align}
$$

Since the first alorithm will always be below $\pi$ and the second one will always be above $\pi$, we can easily determine which are the correct digits of the outputs.

For example after $50$ iterations of the $2$nd step in each algorithm I got the outputs of:

$$
\begin{align}
&\pi \approx 3.141592653589793238462643383279248096286 \text{, and} \\
&\pi \approx 3.141592653589793238462643383280012460020\\
\end{align}
$$
They align up to
$$\pi \approx 3.1415926535897932384626433832$$
Meaning those digits of $\pi$ are certainly correct.

Here is a the code of these algorithms in Python $3.7$ using the MPMath package for mathematical preciseness:

```
import math
from mpmath import mpf, mpc, mp
mp.dps = 10000

def pi_approx_below(iterations,print_partial_results=False,significant_digits=40):
    p = mpf(0.5)
    n = mpf(4)
    for i in range(iterations):
        p = mpf((1-mp.sqrt(1-p))/2)
        n = mpf(2*n)
        if(print_partial_results):
            print("Pi approximation number " + str(i+1) + ": "+ str(mp.nstr(n*mp.sqrt(p),significant_digits)))
    return mp.nstr(n*mp.sqrt(p),significant_digits)

def pi_approx_above(iterations,print_partial_results=False,significant_digits=40):
    p = mpf(1)
    n = mpf(4)
    for i in range(iterations):
        p = mpf((-1+mp.sqrt(1+p ** 2))/p)
        n = mpf(2*n)
        if(print_partial_results):
            print("Pi approximation number " + str(i+1) + ": "+ str(mp.nstr(n*p,significant_digits)))
    return mp.nstr(n*p,significant_digits)

print(pi_approx_below(50))
print(pi_approx_above(50))
```

And its output was:

```
3.141592653589793238462643383279248096286
3.14159265358979323846264338328001246002
```

**Question:** Are these known algorithms?

**Note:** I won't add a proof of why the algoithms work (yet), if the algorithms aren't known. I'd like to keep that to myself for now. Although I doubt I'm the first one who discovered these.

Comment: I mean, you are simply approximating the ratio between the circumference and diameter. Good stuff though. I'd say it's pretty well known.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I started from. But is there anyone who wrote these up in such explicit form?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Polygon_approximation_era

Comment: Hmmm, I read the article but I'm not satisfied. You'd still have to work out all of  the details if you want to make an algorithm based on the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is pretty well known method. Moreover, I remember from school years about combined approximation of $\pi$: $$\pi \approx \dfrac{2\pi_A +\pi_B}{3},$$ where $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ are perimeters of inscribed and circumscribed polygons respectively.
$${ }$$

For example, $n=1024\;$ ($9$th step), then $$\pi_A = 3.1415\color{tan}{877252...},$$ $$\pi_B = 3.141\color{tan}{6025102...},$$
and 
$$
\dfrac{2\pi_A+\pi_B}{3} = 3.141592653\color{tan}{6...}
$$

Comment: Helpful link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesRecurrenceFormula.html - here step $(a_n,b_n) \rightarrow (a_{2n},b_{2n})$ is being performed in {$1$ addition, $3$ multiplications, $1$ division and $1$ square root}. Your method makes it  separetely: $a_n \rightarrow a_{2n}, \;\; b_n \rightarrow b_{2n}$, so it is better for understanding, but needs a bit more operations: {$4$ additions/subtractions, $4$ multiplications, $1$ division and $3$ square roots}. I pretty sure that this variation of Archimedes Recurrence Formula should be used already somewhere.

Comment: (apologies for over-commenting...) here (http://www.pi314.net/eng/archi.php) one can see these recurrent formulas you specified. Difference is in initial polygon only: hexagon instead of square.

Comment: An interesting sequence defined by $$a_1=3$$ $$a_{n+1}=a_n+\sin(a_n)$$ for every positive integer $n$ converges in a cubic rate towards $\pi$.